# How to know the status of background job when disconnected from active session in putty

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a list of shell scripts like:

```
sh test.sh --dir payment --fname payments_1.txt --bdt 20170322
sh test.sh --dir payment --fname payments_2.txt --bdt 20170322
sh test.sh --dir payment --fname payments_3.txt --bdt 20170322
sh test.sh --dir payment --fname payments_4.txt --bdt 20170322
```

and so on like 300 scripts.

So I included them in a file called test_payment and ran "source test_payment &". I know the job runs in background which takes like 6 hours but if I get disconnected from the putty session, how do I know the job is finished?
Are there any other better ways than I did this?
Does "nohup ./test_payment.sh &" work without the source command?

PS: I tried "nohup source ./test_payment" . There is an error failed to run command source.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be a cron job, redirecting STDOUT and STDERR.

Like this:

0 10 *  *  *  /path/your.script 1>/location/stdout.1 2>/location/stderrr.2

Or you can redirect both outputs to the same file, this way:

0 10 *'* * /path/your.script 2>&1 | tee -a /location/log.file

And your script should include at least:

1. Necessary ENV variables
2. Preferred SHELL
3. cd to your running directory

Regards